# Different permalink for posts and authors

Tags: posts, permalinks, author

I tried to avoid ask this question, because I think that must be simple, but after long hours trying to get an answer I cant achieve it.

I am trying to get a permalink structure like this:

```
http://domain.com/u/USERNAME
http://domain.com/p/POSTID
```

To get that structure I set a "Custom structure" in the permalink settings of my Wordpress. This is the value of the custom structure:

```
/p/%post_id%
```

That is great for posts, but not for authors. Using that settings this is the result:

```
http://domain.com/p/u/USERNAME
http://domain.com/p/POSTID
```

And that can be changed via htaccess or functions.php.

Any idea will help me a lot.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just change the `author_base` on the global `$wp_rewrite` object. Also add a field to the Permalink options page, so you can change it at will.

To start: a class to wrap everything up.

```
<?php
class Custom_Author_Base
{
    const SETTING = 'author_base';

    private static $ins = null;

    public static function instance()
    {
        is_null(self::$ins) && self::$ins = new self;
        return self::$ins;
    }

    public static function init()
    {
        add_action('plugins_loaded', array(self::instance(), '_setup'));
    }

    public function _setup()
    {
        // we'll add actions here
    }
}
```

Now, we can hook into admin init and use the settings API to add a field to the permalink page.

```
<?php
class Custom_Author_Base
{
    // snip snip

    public function _setup()
    {
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'fields'));
    }

    public function fields()
    {
        add_settings_field(
            self::SETTING,
            __('Author Base', 'custom-author-base'),
            array($this, 'field_cb'),
            'permalink',
            'optional',
            array('label_for' => self::SETTING)
        );
    }

    public function field_cb()
    {
        printf(
            '<input type="text" class="regular-text" name="%1$s" id="%1$s" value="%2$s" />',
            esc_attr(self::SETTING),
            esc_attr(get_option(self::SETTING))
        );
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the settings API doesn't actually save anything on the permalink page, so you have to hook into `load-options-permalink.php` and do your own saving.

```
<?php
class Custom_Author_Base
{
    // snip snip

    public function _setup()
    {
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'fields'));
        add_action('load-options-permalink.php', array($this, 'maybe_save'));
    }

    public function maybe_save()
    {
        if ('POST' !== $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
            return;
        }

        if (!empty($_POST[self::SETTING])) {
            $res = sanitize_title_with_dashes($_POST[self::SETTING]);
            update_option(self::SETTING, $res);
            $this->set_base($res);
        } else {
            delete_option(self::SETTING);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you need to hook into `init` and set the author base (the `set_base` method used above).

```
<?php
class Custom_Author_Base
{
    // snip snip

    public function _setup()
    {
        add_action('init', array($this, 'set_base'));
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'fields'));
        add_action('load-options-permalink.php', array($this, 'maybe_save'));
    }

    public function set_base($base=null)
    {
        global $wp_rewrite;

        is_null($base) && $base = get_option(self::SETTING);

        if ($base) {
            $wp_rewrite->author_base = $base;
        }
    }
}
```

[As a plugin](https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/WPSE-Plugins/blob/master/custom-author-base.php).

Comment: Im really impressed, thank you for your time making a full plugin to help me, is really awesome!. I made a pull request in your GitHub to finally solve the problem with a small modification. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing what you already have for rewrites you can try this:

You can add this to your`functions.php` (or better: Into a (mu-)plugin):

```
<?php 
/* Plugin Name: (WPSE) 77228 Add /u/ rewrite rules */

add_action( 'init', 'add_author_rules' );  
function add_author_rules()
{   
    add_rewrite_rule(  
        'u/([^/]+)/?',
        'index.php?author=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );  

    add_rewrite_rule(  
        'u/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?",  
        'index.php?author=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );  

    add_rewrite_rule(  
        'u/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?',
        'index.php?author=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );  

    add_rewrite_rule(  
        'u/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?',
        'index.php?author=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',  
        'top'
    );  
}
```

If that doesnt work you must replace `index.php?author=` with `index.php?author_name=` for each entry.

Tell me if it works.

You can test your rewrite rules with the following code in your functions.php.
I always use this code and helped me out a couple of times.
Once you make a rewrite you can see if it shows up correctly.

```
define( 'REWRITE_RULES_INSPECTOR_VERSION', '1.1' );
define( 'REWRITE_RULES_INSPECTOR_ROOT', dirname( __FILE__ ) );
define( 'REWRITE_RULES_INSPECTOR_FILE_PATH' , REWRITE_RULES_INSPECTOR_ROOT . '/' . basename( __FILE__ ) );

class Rewrite_Rules_Inspector
{

var $parent_slug = 'tools.php';
var $page_slug = 'rewrite-rules-inspector';
var $view_cap = 'manage_options';
var $flushing_enabled = true;
var $sources = array();

/**
 * Construct the plugin
 */
function __construct() {

    // This plugin only runs in the admin, but we need it initialized on init
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'action_init' ) );

}

/**
 * Initialize the plugin
 */
function action_init() {

    if ( !is_admin() )
        return;

    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'action_admin_menu' ) );

    // Allow the view to be placed elsewhere than tools.php
    $this->parent_slug = apply_filters( 'rri_parent_slug', $this->parent_slug );

    // Whether or not users can flush the rewrite rules from this tool
    $this->flushing_enabled = apply_filters( 'rri_flushing_enabled', $this->flushing_enabled );

    // User actions available for the rewrite rules page
    if ( isset( $_GET['page'], $_GET['action'] ) && $_GET['page'] == $this->page_slug && $_GET['action'] == 'download-rules' )
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'download_rules' ) );
    elseif ( isset( $_GET['page'], $_GET['action'] ) && $_GET['page'] == $this->page_slug && $_GET['action'] == 'flush-rules' )
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'flush_rules' ) );
    elseif ( isset( $_GET['page'], $_GET['message'] ) && $_GET['page'] == $this->page_slug && $_GET['message'] == 'flush-success' )
        add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this, 'action_admin_notices' ) );

}

/**
 * Add our sub-menu page to the VIP dashboard navigation
 */
function action_admin_menu() {

    add_submenu_page( $this->parent_slug, __( 'Rewrite Rules Inspector', 'rewrite-rules-inspector' ), __( 'Rewrite Rules', 'rewrite-rules-inspector' ), $this->view_cap, $this->page_slug, array( $this, 'view_rules' ) );

}

/**
 * Show a message when you've successfully flushed your rewrite rules
 */
function action_admin_notices() {
    echo '<div class="message updated"><p>' . __( 'Rewrite rules flushed.', 'rewrite-rules-inspector' ) . '</p></div>';
}

/**
 * Get the rewrite rules for the current view
 */
function get_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $rewrite_rules_array = array();
    $rewrite_rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );
    if ( !$rewrite_rules )
        $rewrite_rules = array();
    // Track down which rewrite rules are associated with which methods by breaking it down
    $rewrite_rules_by_source = array();
    $rewrite_rules_by_source['post'] = $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite->permalink_structure, EP_PERMALINK );
    $rewrite_rules_by_source['date'] = $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite->get_date_permastruct(), EP_DATE );
    $rewrite_rules_by_source['root'] = $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite->root . '/', EP_ROOT );
    $rewrite_rules_by_source['comments'] = $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite->root . $wp_rewrite->comments_base, EP_COMMENTS, true, true, true, false );
    $rewrite_rules_by_source['search'] = $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite->get_search_permastruct(), EP_SEARCH );
    $rewrite_rules_by_source['author'] = $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite->get_author_permastruct(), EP_AUTHORS );
    $rewrite_rules_by_source['page'] = $wp_rewrite->page_rewrite_rules();

    // Extra permastructs including tags, categories, etc.
    foreach ( $wp_rewrite->extra_permastructs as $permastructname => $permastruct ) {
        if ( is_array( $permastruct ) ) {
            // Pre 3.4 compat
            if ( count( $permastruct ) == 2 )
                $rewrite_rules_by_source[$permastructname] = $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules( $permastruct[0], $permastruct[1] );
            else
                $rewrite_rules_by_source[$permastructname] = $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules( $permastruct['struct'], $permastruct['ep_mask'], $permastruct['paged'], $permastruct['feed'], $permastruct['forcomments'], $permastruct['walk_dirs'], $permastruct['endpoints'] );
        } else {
            $rewrite_rules_by_source[$permastructname] = $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules( $permastruct, EP_NONE );
        }
    }

    // Apply the filters used in core just in case
    foreach( $rewrite_rules_by_source as $source => $rules ) {
        $rewrite_rules_by_source[$source] = apply_filters( $source . '_rewrite_rules', $rules );
        if ( 'post_tag' == $source )
            $rewrite_rules_by_source[$source] = apply_filters( 'tag_rewrite_rules', $rules );
    }

    foreach( $rewrite_rules as $rule => $rewrite ) {
        $rewrite_rules_array[$rule]['rewrite'] = $rewrite;
        foreach( $rewrite_rules_by_source as $source => $rules ) {
            if ( array_key_exists( $rule, $rules ) ) {
                $rewrite_rules_array[$rule]['source'] = $source;
            }
        }
        if ( !isset( $rewrite_rules_array[$rule]['source'] ) )
            $rewrite_rules_array[$rule]['source'] = 'other';
    }

    // Find any rewrite rules that should've been generated but weren't
    $maybe_missing = $wp_rewrite->rewrite_rules();
    $missing_rules = array();
    $rewrite_rules_array = array_reverse( $rewrite_rules_array, true );
    foreach( $maybe_missing as $rule => $rewrite ) {
        if ( !array_key_exists( $rule, $rewrite_rules_array ) ) {
            $rewrite_rules_array[$rule] = array( 
                'rewrite' => $rewrite,
                'source' => 'missing',
            );
        }
    }
    // Prepend rules so it's obvious
    $rewrite_rules_array = array_reverse( $rewrite_rules_array, true );

    // Allow static sources of rewrite rules to override, etc.
    $rewrite_rules_array = apply_filters( 'rri_rewrite_rules', $rewrite_rules_array );
    // Set the sources used in our filtering
    $sources = array( 'all' );
    foreach( $rewrite_rules_array as $rule => $data ) {
        $sources[] = $data['source'];
    }
    $this->sources = array_unique( $sources );

    if ( ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        $match_path = parse_url( esc_url( $_GET['s'] ), PHP_URL_PATH );
        $wordpress_subdir_for_site = parse_url( home_url(), PHP_URL_PATH );
        if ( ! empty( $wordpress_subdir_for_site ) ) {
            $match_path = str_replace( $wordpress_subdir_for_site, '', $match_path );
        }
        $match_path = ltrim( $match_path, '/' );
    }

    $should_filter_by_source = ! empty( $_GET['source'] ) && 'all' !== $_GET[ 'source' ] && in_array( $_GET['source'], $this->sources );

    // Filter based on match or source if necessary
    foreach( $rewrite_rules_array as $rule => $data ) {
        // If we're searching rules based on URL and there's no match, don't return it
        if ( ! empty( $match_path ) && ! preg_match( "!^$rule!", $match_path ) ) {
            unset( $rewrite_rules_array[$rule] );
        } elseif ( $should_filter_by_source && $data['source'] != $_GET['source'] ) {
            unset( $rewrite_rules_array[$rule] );
        }
    }

    // Return our array of rewrite rules to be used
    return $rewrite_rules_array;

}

/**
 * View the rewrite rules for the site
 */
function view_rules() {

    // Bump view stats or do something else on page load
    do_action( 'rri_view_rewrite_rules' );

    $wp_list_table = new Rewrite_Rules_Inspector_List_Table();
    $wp_list_table->prepare_items();

    ?>
    <style>
        #the-list tr.type-sunrise,
        #the-list tr.type-custom {
            background-color: #EEC7F0;
        }
        #the-list tr.type-sunrise td,
        #the-list tr.type-custom td {
            border-top-color: #F4E6F5;
            border-bottom-color: #EFBBF2;
        }
        #the-list tr.source-missing {
            background-color: #f7a8a9;
        }
        #the-list tr.type-missing td {
            border-top-color: #FECFD0;
            border-bottom-color: #f99b9d;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="wrap">
    <?php screen_icon( 'tools' ); ?>
    <h2><?php _e( 'Rewrite Rules Inspector', 'rewrite-rules-inspector' ); ?></h2>

    <?php
    $rules = $this->get_rules();
    if ( empty( $rules ) ) {
        $error_message = apply_filters( 'rri_message_no_rules', __( 'No rewrite rules yet, try flushing.', 'rewrite-rules-inspector' ) );
        echo '<div class="message error"><p>' . $error_message . '</p></div>';
    } else if ( in_array( 'missing', $this->sources ) ) {
        $error_message = apply_filters( 'rri_message_missing_rules', __( 'Some rewrite rules may be missing, try flushing.', 'rewrite-rules-inspector' ) );
        echo '<div class="message error"><p>' . $error_message . '</p></div>';
    }
    ?>

    <?php if ( ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ): ?>
    <p><?php printf( __( 'A listing of all %1$s rewrite rules for this site that match "<a target="_blank" href="%2$s">%3$s</a>"' ), count( $wp_list_table->items ), esc_url( $_GET['s'] ), esc_url( $_GET['s'] ) ); ?></p>
    <?php else: ?>
    <p><?php printf( __( 'A listing of all %1$s rewrite rules for this site.' ), count( $wp_list_table->items ) ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php $wp_list_table->display(); ?>

    </div>

<?php

}

/**
 * Process a user's request to download a set of the rewrite rules
 * Prompts a download of the current set of rules as a text file by
 * setting the header. Respects current filter rules.
 */
function download_rules() {

    // Check nonce and permissions
    check_admin_referer( 'download-rules' );
    if ( !current_user_can( $this->view_cap ) )
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have permissions to perform this action.' ) );

    // Get the rewrite rules and prompt the user to download them
    // File is saved as YYYYMMDD.themename.rewriterules.txt 
    $theme_name = sanitize_key( get_option( 'stylesheet' ) );
    $filename = date( 'Ymd' ) . '.' . $theme_name . '.rewriterules.txt';
    header( 'Content-Type: text/plain' );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"' );

    $rewrite_rules = $this->get_rules();
    $rules_to_export = array();
    foreach( $rewrite_rules as $rule => $data ) {
        $rules_to_export[$rule] = $data['rewrite'];
    }
    echo var_export( $rules_to_export, true );
    exit;
}

/**
 * Allow a user to flush rewrite rules for their site
 */
function flush_rules() {
    global $plugin_page;

    // Check nonce and permissions
    check_admin_referer( 'flush-rules' );
    if ( !current_user_can( $this->view_cap ) || !$this->flushing_enabled )
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have permissions to perform this action.' ) );

    flush_rewrite_rules( false );
    do_action( 'rri_flush_rules' );

    // Woo hoo!
    $args = array(
            'message' => 'flush-success',
        );
    wp_safe_redirect( add_query_arg( $args, menu_page_url( $plugin_page, false ) ) );
    exit;
}

}

global $rewrite_rules_inspector;
$rewrite_rules_inspector = new Rewrite_Rules_Inspector();

// Load the WP_List_Table class if it doesn't yet exist
if ( !class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) )
require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php';

/**
 * Display the rewrite rules in an easy to digest list table
 */
class Rewrite_Rules_Inspector_List_Table extends WP_List_Table {

/**
 * Construct the list table
 */
function __construct() {

    $screen = get_current_screen();

    parent::__construct( array(
        'plural' => 'Rewrite Rules',
    ) );
}

/**
 * Load all of the matching rewrite rules into our list table
 */
function prepare_items() {
    global $rewrite_rules_inspector;

    $columns = $this->get_columns();
    $hidden = array();
    $sortable = array();
    $this->_column_headers = array( $columns, $hidden, $sortable );

    $this->items = $rewrite_rules_inspector->get_rules();
}

/**
 * What to print when no items were found
 */
function no_items() {
    _e( 'No rewrite rules were found.', 'rewrite-rules-inspector' );
}

/**
 * Display the navigation for the list table
 */
function display_tablenav( $which ) {
    global $plugin_page, $rewrite_rules_inspector;

    $search = ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ? esc_url( $_GET['s'] ) : '';

    if ( $which == 'bottom' )
        return false;
    ?>
    <div class="custom-tablenav-top" style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:10px;">
    <div style="float:right;">
        <?php
        // Only show the flush button if enabled
        if ( $rewrite_rules_inspector->flushing_enabled ):
        ?>
        <?php
            // Flush the current set of rewrite rules
            $args = array(
                    'action' => 'flush-rules',
                    '_wpnonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'flush-rules' ),
                );
            $flush_url = add_query_arg( $args, menu_page_url( $plugin_page, false ) );
        ?>
        <a title="<?php _e( 'Flush your rewrite rules to regenerate them', 'rewrite-rules-inspector' ); ?>" class="button-secondary" href="<?php echo esc_url( $flush_url ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Flush Rules', 'rewrite-rules-inspector' ); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php
            // Prepare the link to download a set of rules
            // Link is contingent on the current filter state   
            $args = array(
                'action' => 'download-rules',
                '_wpnonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'download-rules' ),
            );
            if ( isset( $_GET['source'] ) && in_array( $_GET['source'], $rewrite_rules_inspector->sources ) )
                $args['source'] = sanitize_key( $_GET['source'] );
            else
                $args['source'] = 'all';
            $args['s'] = !empty( $_GET['s'] ) ? $_GET['s'] : '';

            $download_url = add_query_arg( $args, menu_page_url( $plugin_page, false ) );
        ?>
        <a title="<?php _e( 'Download current list of rules as a .txt file', 'rewrite-rules-inspector' ); ?>" class="button-secondary" href="<?php echo esc_url( $download_url ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Download', 'rewrite-rules-inspector' ); ?></a>
    </div>
    <form method="GET">
        <label for="s"><?php _e( 'Match URL:', 'rewrite-rules-inspector' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" id="s" name="s" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $search ); ?>" size="50"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="page" name="page" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $plugin_page ); ?>" />
        <label for="source"><?php _e( 'Rule Source:', 'rewrite-rules-inspector' ); ?></label>
        <select id="source" name="source">
        <?php
            if (isset( $_GET['source'] ) && in_array( $_GET['source'], $rewrite_rules_inspector->sources ) )
                $filter_source = sanitize_key( $_GET['source'] );
            else
                $filter_source = 'all';
            foreach( $rewrite_rules_inspector->sources as $value ) {
                echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" ';
                selected( $filter_source, $value );
                echo '>' . esc_attr( $value ) . '</option>';
            }
        ?>
        </select>
        <?php submit_button( __( 'Filter', 'rewrite-rules-inspector' ), 'primary', null, false ); ?>
        <?php if ( $search || !empty( $_GET['source'] ) ): ?>
            <a href="<?php menu_page_url( $plugin_page ); ?>" class="button-secondary"><?php _e( 'Reset', 'rewrite-rules-inspector' ); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

/**
 * Define the columns for our list table
 */
function get_columns() {

    $columns = array(
            'rule'          => __( 'Rule', 'rewrite-rules-inspector' ),
            'rewrite'       => __( 'Rewrite', 'rewrite-rules-inspector' ),
            'source'        => __( 'Source', 'rewrite-rules-inspector' ),
        );
    return $columns;

}

/**
 * Display each row of rewrite rule data
 */
function display_rows() {
    foreach ( $this->items as $rewrite_rule => $rewrite_data ) {
        $this->single_row( $rewrite_rule, $rewrite_data );
    }
}

/**
 * Display a single row of rewrite rule data
 */
function single_row( $rule, $data ) {

    $source = $data['source'];
    $rewrite = $data['rewrite'];

    $class = 'source-' . $source;

    echo "<tr class='$class'>";

    list( $columns, $hidden ) = $this->get_column_info();

    foreach ( $columns as $column_name => $column_display_name ) {

        switch ( $column_name ) {
            case 'rule':
                echo "<td class='column-rule'><strong>" . esc_html( $rule ) . "</strong></td>";
                break;
            case 'rewrite':
                echo "<td class='column-rewrite'>" . esc_html( $rewrite ) . "</td>";
                break;
            case 'source':
                echo "<td class='column-source'>" . esc_html( $source ) . "</td>";
                break;
        }
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}
}
```

When you're going to rewrite urls, set your permalinks to the option at the top so you have links like `?p=87`. This way you know the structure.

Comment: After you add these rules visit the permalinks section to flush the rewrites.

Comment: Im trying to make it works, but still I can achieve it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated my original answer with some tests you can run..