# How to custom change author base without $this->front?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I have a sample code:

```
function change_author_permalinks() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'u';
    $wp_rewrite->author_structure = "/" . $wp_rewrite->author_base . '/%author%';
    add_rewrite_rule('u/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init','change_author_permalinks');
```

but my current front set on my blog is:

`t%post%` (ex: `www.domain.com/tauthor/username`)

I want change to:

```
www.domain.com/u/username
```

But when run code, result is page not found ? How to fix it ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the matter, but what does `$this->front` has to do with this? As you use it in the title, but not in the content of the Question...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77228/different-permalink-for-posts-and-authors

Answer (score 16):

You're close, but you don't need the `add_rewrite_rule` call.

```
add_action('init', 'wpse82004_init');
function wpse82004_init()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'u';
    $wp_rewrite->author_structure = '/' . $wp_rewrite->author_base . '/%author%';
}
```

After that's in place, just re-save permalinks.

Here's [a plugin](https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/WPSE-Plugins/blob/master/custom-author-base.php) to put an option on your permalinks page to do this.

Comment: What does the author_structure part do that isn't handled by the author_base?  Just curious, because I've not been using that line and it seems to work.

Comment: If you have your permalinks without a "front" it will work.  Eg. `/%year%/%month%/%postname%`.  If there is a front (eg. `/this-is-a-front/%postname%`) it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  I will update my live code based on your answer, so definitely +1 from me!

Comment: Don't forget to save your permalinks after adding this code so it flushes the rewrite rules.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did to change the author base:

```
// change base of author pages- need to save permalinks to take effect
function wpa_82004(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'people'; // or whatever
}
add_action('init','wpa_82004');
```

Once you've run this, be sure to re-save your permalinks. (Options->Permalinks)  You have to flush your rewrite_rules to even know if this is working.