# Custom Permalink Base

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls

To enable all category, single and archive pages to render the url with a prefix of "news".
E.g.

```
www.yourdomain.com/news/category/post-name
```

I set the permalink structure as `/news/%category%/%postname%/` and this works fine.

An issue cropped up during a recent build that has prompted this question. Namely that the site required a custom author section and with the permalink structure set as above author pages were also prefixed with "news", E.g.

```
www.yourdomain.com/news/author/author-name
```

Is there any way to remove the "news" from author pages / archives only and remain on category / single etc?

Comment: see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82219/4771).

Comment: Please see the reply to that answer, this author rewrite ( which I have tried ) doesnt work with a custom front such as "news" added as it still remains

Comment: I just tested with latest WordPress and 2013 theme and it successfully removes the base from author pages.

Comment: I stand corrected, now working just fine, thanks for the pointer