# Add archive slug to default post post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

I want to add `/post/` to the default post post type url. I have tried it by register the 'post' post type as follows:

```
function fdm_register_post_types() {

   // Get post post type object
   $object = get_post_type_object( 'post' );

   // Set rewrite argument
   $object->rewrite = array( 'slug' => 'post', 'with_front' => false );

   // Reregister post type
   register_post_type( 'post', $object );

}
add_action( 'init', 'fdm_register_post_types' );
```

No success.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617820/wordpress-custom-permalink-for-just-posts/15619416#15619416) Stack post, you need to set the permalink structure (under settings -> permalinks) to `/post/%postname%/` and set other post types rewrite argument to:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'post_type_name', 'with_front' => false),
```

This works fine, but when I visit my author pages now. I can only visit them like `/post/author/name/` and not `/author/name/`.

Is there a better solution for editing the 'post' post type or should I change something in the author functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the permalink settings to configure your post permalinks, then modifying the author permalinks seems like the way to go.

I set up the permalink rules like this:

```
/post/%postname%/
```

Then used this code to modify the author permalinks [(source)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82219/2807):

```
// change base of author pages- need to save permalinks to take effect
function wpse82004_change_author_permalink(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'author';
    $wp_rewrite->author_structure = '/' . $wp_rewrite->author_base . '/%author%';
}
add_action( 'init','wpse82004_change_author_permalink' );
```

Remember to save permalinks afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This seems to work, but do you know why this can't be done by editing the 'post' post type rewrite arguments?

Comment: Glad it worked for you (I tested it and it worked for me too.) Author permalinks are not `post` post type permalinks; they are handled independently and there is no UI available to implement the code in the answer.

Comment: No I mean, why am I not able to edit the `post` post type base (without doing it under settings -> permalinks), so that I not even need to edit the author base.

Comment: Pretty sure you'd have to modify the author base to achieve the configuration you're after regardless. The `post` permalink structure is stored under the `permalink_structure` option and that would need to be taken into account to make sure you're not fighting that when changing the settings programmatically.