# Permalink for Author's Posts in a Category

Tags: permalinks

I want to display posts from a particular author has posted in a category. For example:

```
mywordpresssite.com/john/improvement
```

or

```
mywordpresssite.com/improvement/john
```

In the above "John" is the name of the author and "Improvement" is a post category

How would I achieve this?

Comment: This might help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77228/different-permalink-for-posts-and-authors

Answer (score 0):

If you set permalink structure to `/%author%/%category%/` then it will give you the intended URL structure. But that will be applicable even when you click on single post from the post listing page.

Comment: Kind of a partial solution as it won't let me click on posts (as you mentioned). I can add /%postname%/ to the end and that allows it to work. I was, however, after a solution that wouldn't require me to change my permalink structure. Thanks anyway though.